# Upload a binary file with POST in https://web.postman.co/

Tags: rest, postman

I need to upload a binary file to Sharepoint site using REST API graph.microsoft.com. What is the correct form of Body/payload for this? I use these two headers:
Authorization Bearer 
Content-Type application/json

The binary file is XLSX file in my C disk. Later on it will be a file generated by Python code in Azure.

I got:
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format.",

Body: binary

Comment: Hello Hannu! In order to answer your question effectively, we need some more information on it.
Which file did you try to send? would you be able to share the contents of the file on this post?

Also - if you're trying to send a JSON file in postman, be sure that the file is valid JSON (binary is not valid JSON)

Comment: Hi! 

I tried to upload Excel file. But fortunately I found the wright Python syntax by using ChatGPT. 

import requests
test_api_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/XXXXX/drive/root:/example.xlsx:/content'
api_call_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token , 'Content-Type':'application/json'}

with open('c:/temp/hello.xlsx', 'rb') as file:
    api_call_response = requests.put(test_api_url, headers=api_call_headers, data=file.read())

print("SP: api_call_response.status_code:", api_call_response.status_code)

Comment: I found the answer for Python. It was my ultimate target. 

api_call_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token , 'Content-Type':'application/json'}

# Open the binary file and send it in the request body
with open('c:/temp/hello.xlsx', 'rb') as file:
    api_call_response = requests.put(test_api_url, headers=api_call_headers, data=file.read())

Answer (score 2):

You are telling the server side that it should expect JSON from you but you are sending binary info. So the server tries to parse it as JSON and of course fails. Hence your error message: "Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format.". Use `application/octet-stream`